# Doubt in derivation of a proof in Information Theory

Tags: probability, information-theory

In my class we were trying to derive Shanon's Source Theorem, first by proving the equivalent form in a weaker version.

The question is -Consider a biased coin with probability of heads $p \geq \frac{1}{2}$.We want to transfer this inofrmation with the code of minimum expected length.

To Prove-we can construct a code that give any $\epsilon $ for large $n$ there exists a code such that average code length is less than $(1+\delta)nH(p) $ and also the lower limit of the code length is $(1-\delta)nH(p) $

We tried to prove it by first getting the inequalities
$ \frac{2^{nH(p)}}{n+1}\leq{n \choose np} \leq 2^{nH(p)}$ . Both these inequalities are easy to derive. The problem comes with deriving the lower limit we try to prove that in an optimal code the length of the lower probability event is greater than equal to higher probability code, and then try to find the length of one of the events of higher probability an conclude by showing that since the lengths of events with lower probability is going to be more than this the expected length is more than  $(1-\delta)nH(p) $

Hence since  $ \frac{2^{nH(p)}}{n+1}\leq{n \choose np} $   . One of the events containing $np $ heads will be of length greater than $log_{2}\frac{2^{nH(p)}}{n+1}$ . That is $ nH(p) -log_{2}(n+1) $ . However to complete this part of the proof I need to prove the probability of all events with less than $np$ heads is a constant. Is it true for a binomial distribution that for an event with probability of success greater than $c$ where $c$ is some constant independent of $p$? By proving this we can prove that the expected length of the code is greater than $ c \times (nH(p) -log_{2}(n+1)) $ which comes up to $(1-\delta)nH(p) $

Comment: I can't answer your question, but once when I was a kid my father told me that in the 60s he built something that proved Shannon wrong. Of course I didn't understand at the time, and by the time I knew enough and thought to ask him he was dead. I don't know if it's true, but maybe it's all junk!